# Why laravel route must precedence order, otherwise page not found?

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I'm learning how to use Redis in Laravel, and found a strange things like this:
when Route `articles/trending` above on the Route `articles/{article}`, Route `article/trending` can work fine:
[My Router code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7RxS.png)

And When `articles/{article}` above on `articles/trending`, Route `articles/trending` cannot be found?

Who can tell me the reason? and Thank you very much!

Comment: Wild, but educated guess: because `{article}` can in theory be anything. Laravel's Router will always use the first possible match. If you put the `{article}` route first, that's always the fist possible match.

Comment: oh, I feel inspiration spark suddenly. okay, if I take "articles/{article}" first, when I key "article/trending" router in browser, laravel will match the trending as a varible {article}... It seems the reason.

Comment: Cool! I learned something too then today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `{article}` statement in your route is nothing more than a placeholder.

If you put

```
Route::get('articles/{article}')
```

above the other routes that have the structure

```
Route::get('articles/...')
```

then the `{article}` statement will just catch everything you put after the `/`.

This is because Laravel's Router (and AFAIK, every router for whatever langauge or framework) seeks for the first possible match between URL and defined routes.

`{article}` is a placeholder, and if defined first, will always be the first possible match.

Comment: Okay, I see, Thank you, guys. That was a big help!